# Moving cursor in a game using pyautoit makes the cursor always look up/down

Tags: python, directx, autoit

I am trying to automate cursor movement in a DirectX game, where usually the cursor remains on the crosshair(middle of screen).

Im using python and the only library that I found that interacts with DirectX games' mouse movement is pyautoit.

It is the only library I manage to move the cursor in-game with like I'm moving the mouse myself, but for some reason, no matter where I try to move it, the character keeps looking straight up/down, even if I move the cursor(using python) to the center of the screen. It is as if I'm constantly looking either up or down, no matter where the cursor is moved to.

Here is my code:

```
import autoit

autoit.mouse_move(x, y, 1)
# x and y are coordinates on the screen, the third param should be speed(?) I have played with it 
# and found no difference in the execution of the code.
```

basically no matter what x and y are, the in-game character will always look straight up/down, even if x and y are the middle of the screen, where the cursor usually rests while in game.

Anyone has an idea how can I automate the cursor movement so the cursor will move in-game? (as if it was a shooting game and you are trying to automate the gun movement or wand movement in a magic game)

Comment: The speed parameter ranges from 0 (instantaneous) to 100 (slowest).
The default value is 10.
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm

Answer (score 0):

Modern games use DirectX which takes DirectInputs scan codes instead of VKs. Try using the PyDirectInput module as it uses DirectInput scan codes. If the problem persists, it's probably because the game has a kernel level anti-cheat that blocks win32 api calls that these modules use to move the mouse. If that's the case, you'll have to use a driver that operates at the kernel level to move the mouse.